# Amazon Connect - cannot debug error in Get Customer Input Stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am just new to Amazon Connect and Lex and have just starting creating simple projects. I already have created an entire contact flow which uses Lex and Lambda for routing. Problem is in the "Get Customer Input" stage, it seems to always go to the error output and I could not figure out why. I tried to check if there's any way I can find logs for each stages in the contact flow but could not find any.

Can anyone help me solve this issue? I need to see logs to find out the cause of the error.

EDIT: I got the contact flow logs from cloudwatch. See below. I can't find any significant error from it.

```
{
    "Results": "Error",
    "ContactId": "<contact-id>",
    "ContactFlowId": "<the contact flow id>",
    "ContactFlowModuleType": "GetUserInput",
    "Timestamp": "2019-07-08T08:27:01.185Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting error because you are getting ***error from your Lex*** and that is why the flow is going in error.
You can check the logs for connect and Lex in Amazon service - **Amazon CloudWatch**.

You can also provide details from logs/screenshot what exactly error you are getting, so that I can help.

Comment: i got the logs from cloudwatch but didnt find anything useful to tell me the cause of the error. I posted the logs above

Comment: This log says that you are getting error from lex. Can you check the log of lex. You will find the same in cloudwatch.

Comment: i found the cause of the error. The lex alias I entered was wrong that is why it would not work. The thing is the logs showed nothing like that. I just found it out by double checking the configuration I set. Did not see something like "lex alias not found" in the cloud watch logs of amazon connect.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to language settings mismatch.

If you're using LexV2 make sure you set the proper Language Attribute as well. Easiest way is using the set Voice block in your Contact Flow, on the very bottom of the block you can enable "set language attribute".

Original answer: https://repost.aws/questions/QUn9bLLnclQxmD_DMBgfB9_Q/amazon-connect-error-using-lex-as-customer-input